# PHP Shortcode Regex issue

Tags: php, regex, shortcode

Hi so I need help in taking a block of html which contains existing shortcode for an old arbitrary system. Taking the code below and and using PHP change so the following :

`[CDC](http://www.cdc.gov/)`

would be transformed into this :

```
<a href="http://cdc.gov">CDC</a>
```

Any ideas on how i could achive this? There could be multiple instances in one block of code also. If anybody can help , I'd be grateful - thank you!!

Comment: *There could be multiple instances in one block of code also* - how that, can you visualize such case?

Comment: Not sure what you mean but as an example - this block of text:

"Two excellent websites outlining the major precautions are: '[www.cdc.gov](http://www.cdc.gov/)' and '[www.who.int](http://www.who.int/)' which are the official sites for the centers of disease control prevention and the World health organization respectively."

has 2 instances of the shortcode. I'd need it to convert both instances to their respective links.

Comment: Ahh - ironically SE is changing the shortcodes as they are in my comment :( - its exactly what i need wow

Comment: so, those occurrences like `'www.cdc.gov'` actually look like `[TEXT]('www.cdc.gov')`  in source code?

Comment: Exactly. `[LINK_TEXT](LINK_URL)`

Comment: @Fearghal Not that these are not shortcodes, this is a Markdown syntax for links. For the reference on shortcodes, please look at my library documentation: https://github.com/thunderer/Shortcode .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution using `preg_replace` function with specific regex pattern:

```
$block = "Two excellent websites outlining the major precautions are: [some text](www.cdc.gov) and [who's next](www.who.int) which are the official sites ...";

$block = preg_replace("/\[([^]]+)\]\(([^)]+)\)/", '<a href="$2">$1</a>', $block);

print_r($block);
```

The output(from source code):

```
Two excellent websites outlining the major precautions are: <a href="www.cdc.gov">some text</a> and <a href="www.who.int">who's next</a> which are the official sites ...
```

Answer (score 0):

**This should Work:**
**PHP:**

```
<?php 
$re = '/(?<=\[)[^]]+(?=\])|(?<=\()[^]]+(?=\))/m';
$str = '[CDC](http://www.cdc.gov/)';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

// Print the entire match result
//print_r($matches); //Print result
$url = $matches[0][1]; //http://www.cdc.gov/
$text_url = $matches[0][0]; //CDC
echo "<a href=".$url.">$text_url</a>"
 ?>
```

**Result:**

```
<a href=http://www.cdc.gov/>CDC</a>
```

**Enjoy.**